How to query PostgreSQL table for common elements in array column and aggregate results?
I have the following schema in PostgreSQL 12:
CREATE TABLE test_aggregate(
  id_semilavorato text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  array_allestimenti text[]
);

INSERT INTO test_aggregate VALUES ('A',ARRAY['IDA1','IDA2']);
INSERT INTO test_aggregate VALUES ('B',ARRAY['IDA1']);
INSERT INTO test_aggregate VALUES ('C',ARRAY['IDA2']);
INSERT INTO test_aggregate VALUES ('D',ARRAY['IDA3']);
INSERT INTO test_aggregate VALUES ('E',ARRAY['IDA4']); 

I would like to create a query to obtain groups of semi-finished products and their respective common setups that share at least one element. In this case, that returns 3 records with 2 columns of type text[] and text[], where each record contains semilavorati_comuni (common semi-finished products) and allastimenti_comuni (common setups).
The expected result would be:
semilavorati_comuni | allastimenti_comuni
{A,B,C} | {IDA1,IDA2}
{D}     | {IDA3}
{E}     | {IDA4}

How can I make this query?

That's one of the primary uses of a recursive cte.

I will look the recursive cte.. thanks


Select all rows in the table to wrap the id_semilavorato in an array[].
Join that with the table, pairing up each row based on allastimenti_comuni overlap with && and checking if the other group isn't already in it. To only get (A,B) without also getting the symmetric (B,A) pairing, only join higher id_semilavorato to lower ones.
In each pair, concatenate their allastimenti_comuni arrays with || and append the new id_semilavorato onto semilavorati_comuni with array_append().
Do that again (and again, iteratively) until you find no more overlaps. That'll be handled by the recursive CTE behaviour.
Afterwards, sort each group and keep only unique elements in each of them. You can do that by opening them up with unnest() closing back up with array_agg(distinct e order by e).
Keep only the largest groups by checking if anything larger exists that shares any elements.

demo at db<>fiddle
with recursive cte as (
  select array[id_semilavorato] as semilavorati_comuni
        ,array_allestimenti as allastimenti_comuni
  from test_aggregate
  union all
  select array_append(cte.semilavorati_comuni,id_semilavorato)
        ,cte.allastimenti_comuni || t2.array_allestimenti
  from cte join test_aggregate t2 
  on cte.allastimenti_comuni && t2.array_allestimenti
  and array_position(cte.semilavorati_comuni,t2.id_semilavorato) is null
  and semilavorati_comuni[1] < t2.id_semilavorato)
select distinct 
  (select array_agg(distinct e order by e)
   from unnest(semilavorati_comuni)e)semilavorati_comuni
 ,(select array_agg(distinct e order by e)
   from unnest(allastimenti_comuni)e)allastimenti_comuni
from cte n1
where not exists(
  select from cte n2 
  where n1.allastimenti_comuni && n2.allastimenti_comuni
  and array_length(n2.allastimenti_comuni,1)
     >array_length(n1.allastimenti_comuni,1));




semilavorati_comuni
allastimenti_comuni




{A,B,C,L,M}
{IDA1,IDA2}


{D}
{IDA3}


{E}
{IDA4}


{F,G,H}
{IDA5,IDA6}


{I,J,K}
{IDA0,IDA7,IDA8,IDA9}



With the additional set-based operators provided in intarray extension some of the logic here could be a bit simpler and faster if these were all integer identifiers .

The results shown are from an extended test with test cases added. There's a transitive relation (I and K have no elements in common, but I shares one with J and J shares one with K), some duplicates (L and M are copies of B), plus a reordered group (F is the same as G but reversed).

Incorrect results according to OP "obtain groups of semi-finished products and their respective common setups that share at least one element" K and I have no elements in common and there is no mention of transitivity.

@PepeNO If you could demonstrate a test case this answer is failing, I'll be happy to take a look and address that.

I have realized that transitivity comes implicit in the solution, the only issue with your answer could be performance with a much larger input table due to recursivity limitations.

This problem could be solved programmatically in a much better performant way, than using just queries or recursive queries that have performance problems like stack overflow, memory overhead and an execution time that will increase exponentially as 1s vs many minutes (in tests with rows above 300).
Like this:
create or replace function get_common_elements() 
returns table (sl_comuni text[], all_comuni text[]) as $$
declare 
    rec record;
    arr_alles text[];
    arr_ids text[];
    num_loops int;
begin   
    /*number of iterations in the main loop equal to the number of rows 
    in the worst case (no commons for any)*/ 
    select count(id_semilavorato) into num_loops from test_aggregate;
    --initialize variables to seek common setups
    select array[id_semilavorato], array_allestimenti into arr_ids, arr_alles 
    from test_aggregate order by 1 limit 1;
    --temporary table to store the temp_results
    create temporary table if not exists 
    temp_results (semilavorati_comuni text[], allestimenti_comuni text[]);  
    truncate table temp_results;    
    for i in reverse num_loops..1 loop
        --seek common setups and group ids, in each iteration are discarded groups already found
        for rec in select id_semilavorato, array_allestimenti 
                    from test_aggregate t left join temp_results r 
                    on array[id_semilavorato] && semilavorati_comuni 
                    where semilavorati_comuni is null 
                    order by 1
        loop            
            if arr_alles && rec.array_allestimenti and not rec.id_semilavorato = any(arr_ids) then           
                arr_ids := array_append(arr_ids, rec.id_semilavorato);
                --form commons array
                select array_agg(e) into arr_alles 
                from (  select unnest(arr_alles) e      
                        union
                        select unnest(rec.array_allestimenti) e 
                        order by 1
                    )t;             
            end if;
        end loop;
        insert into temp_results values (arr_ids, arr_alles);
        --obtain new values to seek commons
        select array[id_semilavorato], array_allestimenti into arr_ids, arr_alles
            from test_aggregate t left join temp_results r 
            on array[id_semilavorato] && semilavorati_comuni 
            where semilavorati_comuni is null 
            order by 1 limit 1;
        --if there are not more to seek, break the main loop
        if arr_ids is null and arr_alles is null then
            exit;
        end if;     
    end loop;
    return query select semilavorati_comuni, allestimenti_comuni from temp_results;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

and then
select * from get_common_elements();

Fiddle with extended test case
Fiddle with an input of 300 rows

Incorrect results.

as @Zagarek says it works with my example data, but it doesn't work with more complex data

@AndreaBoc Credo che hai ragione, I'll try to fix it later.

@AndreaBoc have edited my answer to give correct results and better performance.

@PepeNO Your attempt to fix and optimise is commendable, but it is still incorrect. It looks like you forgot to include test cases with more than one element in the array, and this code fails that test: IDA36 ends up in 3 different groups. At the end of the demo you can find a table showing how many times each element ended up in a different group - quite a lot of them repeat that way.

@Zegarek I see you edited the comment adding an explanation, I'll check that.

@PepeNO It just spawns 300 input rows but compared to your test, it also gives them a chance to start off with more than one element in their array. Your function runs and you can simply ctrl+f an element and see how many times it's shown on the page - turns out it gets highlighted in multiple output rows. At the end I just unnested all the resulting arrays and counted repetitions of each element, which showed there's a lot of that.

At a first glance looks like the result (due to transitivity) needs another pass and another (recursion) until there is just one appearance of each ID.
